# How to inset multiple documents in mongoose with mongoose required validation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I wanted to insert multiple documents in my MongoDB collection. I was able to do that by using Model.collection.insert function but when I insert those data it skip/bypass required validation.

I've tried `Model.collection.insert([{data: '1'}, {data: '2'}, {type: '3'}])` but this way it's skip or bypass the validation. I want data field required and I used in my Schema that as required. But that's not working.

There is my schema that required a field.

```
export const SubjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: [true, "title field required"] },
    groups_id: { type: String },
    class_id: { type: String },
    meta: { type: Object }
},
    { timestamps: true })
```

Here is my function

```
    async createSubject(body) {
        let result = SubjectSchema.collection.insert(body)
        return result
    }
```

I want multiple data to be stored and in each record, `title` field should be required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Model.insertMany([{data: '1'}, {data: '2'}, {type: '3'}])
```

you can find the insertMany [ref here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

however, you can also [db.collection.validate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.validate/)

Comment: Brother, I wanted those single objects as validate. See above what I tried yet. I want validation. I know how to insert many documents but my concern is this way it is skipping validation. And storing without `title`

Comment: try mongoose middlewares `SubjectSchema.pre('save', validationFunction);`

Comment: Look like this answer will work because in mongoose docs, it says that: Mongoose always validates each document before sending insertMany to MongoDB.

Comment: happy to help brother ^_^